# Closed set mapped to a not closed example

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity

Give an example for the following cases:

1. A closed set $S \in \Bbb R$ and a continuous function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R,$ such that $f(S)$ is not closed.
2. A bounded set $S \in \Bbb R \setminus0$ and a continuous function $f$ defined on $ \Bbb R \setminus0$ such that $f(S)$ is not bounded

For the first one, I thought to take $S$ to be $\Bbb R$, and the function $f(x)=x$, but I guess it doesnt work because the result is still open and closed. I have no idea for the second one. Help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A huge hint for 2) is that the function isn't defined for 0.  Find a unbounded function that isn't defined at zero and consider f((0,1)).

Comment: First: what about $f=\arctan$, with the closed set $S=\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

A hint for the first one: $S$ can't be bounded. Otherwise $S$ would be compact, hence $f(S)$ would be compact too, and closed. So try something along the lines of $S = [0,+\infty[$ and $f(x) = \arctan x$.

For the second one, look at fleablood's hint in the comments. When you study single variable calculus you see a function exactly like in the hint, you compute its lateral limits at zero, etc. Ring any bells?

Answer (score 0):

For the first, how about a function $f : [0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ that oscillates between very large values and very small positive values? Something along the lines of $f(x) = e^{x \sin x}$.

Any function with a vertical asymptote will take certain bounded sets to unbounded sets, e.g. $f(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: would $f(x)= \tan x$ work for the second one since it has vertical asymptotes?